# How to update Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to change the `ingredients` and measures for some recipes but I can't figure out how to..
My ingredient array from `RecipeDetails` looks like this:

```
{
ingredient1: 'Self-raising Flour', 
ingredient1Measure: '750g', 
ingredient2: 'Sugar', 
ingredient2Measure: '6 tablespoons', 
ingredient3: 'Eggs', …}
```

And the code looks like this

```
const RecipeDetails = ({
    id,
    ingredients,
    instructions,
  }) => {

    const SaveChanges= ({
        oldIngredient,
        oldMeasure,
        newIngredient,
        newMeasure,
      }) => {
        
        // CHANGE INGREDIENT AND MEASURE
      };

    return (
        <div></div>
      );
};

RecipeDetails.propTypes = {
  id: types.string.isRequired,
  ingredients: types.object.isRequired,
  instructions: types.string.isRequired,
};

export default RecipeDetails;
```

Comment: `{
ingredient1: 'Self-raising Flour', 
ingredient1Measure: '750g', 
ingredient2: 'Sugar', 
ingredient2Measure: '6 tablespoons', 
ingredient3: 'Eggs', …}` is not an array, it is an object with properties

Comment: Could you give an example of what you would like the object to look like after a change is made? Are the "oldIngredient" and "oldMeasure" parameters strings like "Sugar" and "6 tablespoons", or are they the keys of the values you want to change like "ingredient1" and "ingredient1Measure"?

Comment: Further to @JacobK's comment, if the `oldIngredient` and `oldMeasure` are keys, then simply try `ingredients[oldIngredient] = newIngredient; ingredient[oldMeasure] = newMeasure;`. If those two are values, try using `Object.entries(ingredient).find(([k, v]) => v === oldIngredient)` to get the key-value pair. Now, use the key to change the corresponding value.